# Do we need a review of unanswered questions?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Back after an hospitalization and leaving alcohol, fortunately for my health. I will be quiet.

I realized we have a lot of unsanswered questions. I made a review and four of them were easy to me, a graduated, to answer.

The point I have seen at stackoverflow of this site is for people consultating questions directly from google searcher.

So I wonder, if me, not working on geology, could answer four of them, wouldn't you need to copy what I did, search for unasnwered questions on the inbox and solve it for students falling on the site?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've also browsed unanswered questions a few times, and I definitely agree with you that it is a good practice. Thanks for doing that!